# How do I call stored procedure with JSON parameter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is the stored procedure and it's call

**Stored Procedure (test)**

```
BEGIN


  DECLARE Query1 VARCHAR(500);  
    ...
    ...

   SET @Query1 = CONCAT('INSERT INTO tblName (col1, col2)   values("',v_value1,'","',v_value2,'")'
    ); 

  PREPARE 
    stmt 
  FROM 
    @Query1;
  EXECUTE 
    stmt;
```

**Stored Procedure Call to test**

```
CALL test( "abc",'{"pqr":true,"xyz":false}' );
```

When I try below then it's working fine but it's not working when I try to give parameters with above double quotes

```
CALL test( "abc","{'pqr':true,'xyz':false}" ); //Working fine
```

**Error**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'pqr":true,"xyz":false'

Comment: can you include full code which fails?

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's a late answer...

It has to do with the way MySQL handles quotes

Whenever you include something into single quotes MySQL is going to treat it as a string.

For example:

> "1" - could be treated as an integer if it is inserted into integer
>   field...
>
> But
>
> '1' - is going to be treated as a string no matter what.